# BigQuery: inner join Field not found in table

Tags: google-bigquery

This is pretty basic so I do not know why it does not work.

I am trying to get rows from a table with udids that are in another table.

Query:

```
SELECT aliasA.udid, aliasA.score 
FROM (TABLE_QUERY(TableA,'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, "Scores_2014_04_01_5")')) as aliasA
INNER JOIN ProjectB.udids as aliasB
ON aliasA.udid = aliasB.udid
```

Error:

```
Field 'aliasA.udid' not found in table 'TableA.Scores_2014_04_01_5'.
```

but there are fields "udid" in both tables

Please help me, this should be so simple I am going crazy!

It seems that the problem is with `(TABLE_QUERY(TableA,'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, "Scores_2014_04_01_5")')) as aliasA`, since if I use `TableA.Scores_2014_04_01_5` it works.

However, it is crucial for me to use the TABLE_QUERY!

Comment: Why are you using `TABLE_QUERY` here? Are there a bunch of tables you are looking at?

Comment: Yes, I have a bunch of them :)

Comment: What do the names of the tables look like?

Comment: but it looks like I will not be able to do that. Now I get an error:  "A query cannot have both UNION and JOIN" Is there a way out of this?

Comment: You should just try to use `CONTAINS` instead of using `REGEXP_MATCH`

Comment: CONTAINS does not fix it, but your other idea solved an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases dont seem to be working with `TABLE_QUERY`. One quick workaround might be to use a SELECT inside like in the snippet below.

```
SELECT aliasA.udid, aliasA.score 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(TableA,'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, "Scores_2014_04_01_5")')) as aliasA
INNER JOIN ProjectB.udids as aliasB
ON aliasA.udid = aliasB.udid
```

Comment: That is it! it works, and it even does not complain about union and join! Thank you, great workaround! :)